# Create number objects

Tags: objective-c, ios

Let's say I want to create 255 number objects.

```
 NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    int x = 255;

    for(int y = 0; y < x; y++)
    {
        [arr addObject: [NSNumber  //for example NSString have initWithFormat method how to achieve that with NSNumber ?];
    }
```

Well, how to do that ?

Answer (score 4):

```
int x = 255;

for(int y = 0; y < x; y++)
{
    [arr addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:y]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

NSNumber has a *ton* of initializers and convenience constructors  -- here's one which seems suitable for you:

```
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:y]];
```

Answer (score 2):

That's all you need

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

int x = 255;

for(int y = 0; y < x; y++)
{
    [arr addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:y]];
}
```